# Split datetime SQL Server 2008

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns `StartDate, EndDate, ElapsedTimeInSec`.

I use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to calculate the `ElapsedTimeInSec`.

I would like to do this:

- If my start date is `2011-11-18 07:30:00` and my end date `2011-11-18 9:30:00` which give me a `ElapsedtimeInSec` of 7200 I would like to be able to split it this way.
- Row 1 : 2011-11-18 07:30:00 / 2011-11-18 08:00:00 / 1800
- Row 2 : 2011-11-18 08:00:00 / 2011-11-18 09:00:00 / 3600
- Row 3 : 2011-11-18 09:00:00 / 2011-11-18 09:30:00 / 1800

How can I achieve this result ?

I dont think I made my explaination clear enough.

I have an actual table with data in it which as 2 field one with a StratDowntime and one with a EndDowntime and I would like to create a view of hours per hour base on a production shift of 12 hours (07:00:00 to 19:00:00) of the downtime.

So If I have a downtime from 2011-11-19 06:00:00 to 2011-11-19 08:00:00 I want in my report to see from 07:00:00 so the new rocrd should look like 2011-11-19 07:00:00 to 2011-11-19 08:00:00.

Another example if I do have downtime from 2011-11-19 10:30:00 to 2011-11-19 13:33:00 I should get in my report this
          - 2011-11-19 10:30:00 to 2011-11-19 11:00:00
          - 2011-11-19 11:00:00 to 2011-11-19 12:00:00
          - 2011-11-19 12:00:00 to 2011-11-19 13:00:00
          - 2011-11-19 13:00:00 to 2011-11-19 13:33:00

I hope this will clarify the question because none of the solution down there is actually doing this it is close but not on it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME    = '11/18/2011 07:30:00',
        @EndDate    DATETIME    = '11/18/2011 09:30:00',
        @Runner     DATETIME


IF DATEDIFF (mi, @StartDate, @EndDate) < 60

    BEGIN

        SELECT  @StartDate,
                @EndDate,
                DATEDIFF (s, @StartDate, @EndDate)

        RETURN  

    END     

SET @Runner = CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), @StartDate, 101) + ' ' + CAST (DATEPART(hh, @StartDate) + 1 AS VARCHAR) + ':00:00'

WHILE   @Runner <= @EndDate

    BEGIN

        SELECT  @StartDate,
                @Runner,
                DATEDIFF (s, @StartDate, @Runner)

        SET @StartDate  = @Runner
        SET @Runner     = DATEADD(hh, 1, @Runner)

    END

SET @Runner = CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), @EndDate, 101) + ' ' + CAST (DATEPART(hh, @EndDate) AS VARCHAR) + ':00:00'

SELECT  @Runner,
        @EndDate,
        DATEDIFF (s, @Runner, @EndDate)
```

Comment: There are a couple of validations to make, but I think this is a general idea of how to split the times in the ranges that were provided

Comment: Added validation for when the start time and end time fall in the same hour range

Comment: With some modification I was able to make a function that work thanks

Answer (score 0):

CTE:

```
DECLARE @beginDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME

SELECT  @beginDate = '2011-11-18 07:30:00',
        @endDate = '2011-11-18 09:33:10'

DECLARE @mytable TABLE
(
    StartDowntime DATETIME,
    EndDowntime DATETIME,
    ElapsedDowntimesec INT 
)


-- Recursive CTE
;WITH Hours 
(
    BeginTime, 
    EndTime, 
    Seconds 
)
AS 
(
    -- Base case
    SELECT  @beginDate,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, @beginDate) * -1 ) + 60, @beginDate),
            DATEDIFF
            (
                SECOND, 
                @beginDate, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @endDate < DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, @beginDate) * -1 ) + 60, @beginDate) THEN @endDate
                    ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, @beginDate) * -1 ) + 60, @beginDate)
                END
            )
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive
    SELECT  Hours.EndTime,
            CASE 
                WHEN @endDate < DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, Hours.BeginTime) * -1 ) + 120, Hours.BeginTime) THEN @endDate
                ELSE DATEADD(minute, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, Hours.BeginTime) * -1 ) + 120, Hours.BeginTime)
            END,
            DATEDIFF
            (
                SECOND, 
                Hours.EndTime, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @endDate < DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, Hours.BeginTime) * -1 ) + 120, Hours.BeginTime) THEN @endDate
                    ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, ( DATEPART(MINUTE, Hours.BeginTime) * -1 ) + 120, Hours.BeginTime)
                END
            )
            FROM     Hours
            WHERE    Hours.BeginTime < @endDate
)
INSERT INTO @myTable
SELECT  *
FROM    Hours
WHERE   BeginTime < @endDate


SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

Results

```
BeginTime                     EndTime                   Seconds
2011-11-18 07:30:00.000       2011-11-18 08:00:00.000   1800
2011-11-18 08:00:00.000       2011-11-18 09:00:00.000   3600
2011-11-18 09:00:00.000       2011-11-18 09:33:10.000   1990
```

Comment: Hi, this code works but where do i add my table in this code. My table is called Downtime and i have 3 field StartDowntime, EndDowntime and ElapsedDowntimesec. thanks

Comment: Replace @myTable with Downtime

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table valued function applied like `SELECT * FROM [dbo].split('2011-11-02 12:55:00','2011-11-02 13:05:00')`

Function defintion:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split] (@d1 DATETIME, @d2 DATETIME)
    RETURNS @result TABLE (
        StartDate DATETIME, 
        EndDate DATETIME, 
        ElapsedTimeSeconds INT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Store intermediate values in @tmp, using ix as driver for start times.
        DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ix INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY
            , d1 DATETIME, d2 DATETIME)

        -- Insert first hole hour lower than start time
        INSERT INTO @tmp (d1) SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, -1, @d1), -1)

        -- Calculate expected number of intervals
        DECLARE @intervals INT = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @d1, @d2) - 1

        -- insert all intervals
        WHILE @intervals > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tmp (d1, d2) select top 1 d1, d2 FROM @tmp
            SET @intervals = @intervals - 1
        END

        -- Set start and end time for all whole hour intervals
        UPDATE @tmp SET d1 = DATEADD(hour, ix, d1)
            , d2 = DATEADD(hour, ix + 1, d1) 

        -- Set correct start time for first interval
        UPDATE @tmp SET d1 = @d1 WHERE d1 <= @d1

        -- Insert end interval
        INSERT INTO @tmp (d1, d2) 
            SELECT MAX(d2), @d2 FROM @tmp

        -- Delete non-empty last interval
        DELETE FROM @tmp WHERE d1 = d2

        -- Insert @tmp to @result
        INSERT INTO @result (StartDate, EndDate)
        SELECT d1, d2 FROM @tmp

        -- Set interval lengths
        UPDATE @result SET ElapsedTimeSeconds = DATEDIFF(second, StartDate, EndDate)

        return 
    END
    GO
```

To get a result from an existing table, you can use `CROSS APPLY`. Assuming a table `YourTable` with `StartTime` and `EndTime` you can do something like

```
SELECT s.*, y.* FROM YourTable y
cross apply dbo.split(y.StartTime, y.EndTime) s
WHERE y.EndTime < '2011-09-11'
```

to get a result with a kind of join between input data and output table.

Comment: What I have its a table with 2 columns start and end time I would like to be able to do SELECT Start, End From MyTable WHERE Start>= '2011-11-20 07:00:00' AND End<= '2011-11-20 19:00:00' and have the result in hour span.  But here some typical value I have (1) 2011-11-18 07:30:00 / 2011-11-18 08:00:00 (2) 2011-11-18 10:23:39 / 2011-11-18 11:35:20 ...... How can I make this happen? thanks

Comment: You can cross apply the function with the table data, see edit.